# insertColumnsAfter creates more columns than requested

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm requesting to add a column to a spreadsheet, copying the current last (formulas and all) to the new last column:

```
function addCol(ss,shName) {
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(shName), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(1,lCol,lRow,lCol);
  sh.insertColumnsAfter(lCol,1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(1, lCol+1, lRow, lCol+1), {contentsOnly:false});
  return sh;
}
```

Calling that function add two columns to the spreadsheet.  The code still works (sets-up a new column after the current last active column... but also adds a blank column afterwards), but trying to keep the number of columns at a minimum, and this is growing columns at twice the requests.

... I have a "mirror" function that inserts a row at the bottom of a spreadsheet, and only inserts one as requested.  So, I'm guessing this is some sort of normal behavior for Google to add columns for no reason.

Any ideas why 2 columns are created every time I ask for one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To copy last col to new last col try this -

```
function addCol(ss,shName) {
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName(shName), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(1,lCol,lRow,1);
  sh.insertColumnsAfter(lCol,1);
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(1, lCol+1, lRow, 1), {contentsOnly:false});
  return sh;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh... the problem being the last two args are a number of rows and columns, not the end of the range... Thanks